# Out of scope and Invalid Summary error on NSArray

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray

I am trying to create the `UIPickerview` as described in the iPhone development book by Dave Mark. I have a `NSArray` which is declared as a property in the h file which will store the data for the `UIPickerview`. So here is what I have:

in the .h file:

```
@interface RootViewController : UIViewController {
    NSArray *dateForPicker;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dateforPicker;
@end
```

In the **.m** file `viewDidLoad` method (I do have `@synthesize` for the`dateForPicker` property at the beginning of the **.m** file):

```
NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];
self.dateforPicker = tempArray;
[tempArray release];
```

When the `UIPickerview` comes up, it comes up with **"?"** in all the rows. So when I used a breakpoint to inspect the values of tempArray and dateForPicker in the `viewDidLoad` method, I find that the `tempArray` is fine but the `dateForPicker` never gets the values from the `tempArray`. Xcode says **"Invalid Summary"** for the `dateForPicker` array and has **"out of scope**" as the values for the five rows. What is going on? As described by the book, this should work.

Here is the code for the UIPickerView:

```
#pragma mark - 
#pragma mark picker data source methods

-(NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [dateforPicker count];
}

#pragma mark picker delegate methods

-(NSString *)pickView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row
     forComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    return [dateforPicker objectAtIndex:row];
}
@end
```

Comment: Post some more code such as the picker invocation and how it accesses the dateforPicker ivar.

Comment: Single step through the code and do "po self ->dateForPicker" in the console window after you assign dateForPicker its value.  Then similarly check dateForPicker when it's referenced in the picker delegate routine or wherever.

Comment: I did a po self->dateForPicker after it got assigned the values from tempArray. The output was "Can't print the description of a NIL object".

Comment: Check whether UIPickerView outlets are still connected (datasource&delegate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems with your code. I'm not clear if you've typed this into the question manually or copied and pasted from your actual code:

- You are setting `self.dateforPicker` and not `self.dateForPicker`, there is a difference in capitalisation between your ivar and your property. In iOS the compiler will have synthesized a `dateforPicker` ivar when you declared your property, which was set in your `viewDidLoad`, but in your other methods you may be referring to the `dateForPicker` ivar, which is never touched.
- Your `RootViewController` does not declare that it implements the `UIPickerViewDataSource` or `UIPickerViewDelegate` protocols
- Your declaration of the `titleForRow` method is wrong - yours begins with `pickView` rather than `pickerView` so will not get called.

If you have the correct number of rows in your component (you said multiple question marks, how many?), so it looks like the data source is wired up properly, but you also need to connect the delegate, as this is what actually supplies the values for each row. The datasource, confusingly, only supplies the number of components and the number of rows per component.

Comment: Thank you! You are right. It was the capitalization that was the cause. I have fixed the capitalization issues and the UIPickerView comes up with values. There is something strange going on though. When I step through the code and look at the values of tempArray, the debugger shows the 6 objects without any problem when I do mouseover on tempArray. When I mouse over dateForPicker, it still shows "invalid summary" but when I click on the arrow, it shows the 6 rows with a comment "Invalid Summary" for every row. I feel that something is still wrong which might trip me up later.  Whats going on?